# Generate pdf in android with hindi or custom fonts

Tags: android, android-studio, pdf, itext, hindi

Do we have some clear guide on how to generate pdf in android which includes tabular data too, with custom fonts like devnagri etc? I have tried itext pdf but text other than English shows blank. Any free or paid library will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you can draw it on screen then you can draw it to a pdf with the built in [PdfDocument Class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument) as you can use any laid out view (either got from what is already on screen or manually laying it out yourself) and then use the View's [draw](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#draw(android.graphics.Canvas)) method to draw it to the PDF.

So for the tabular data you can use a TableLayout or other methods and the standard fonts available to your app.

Note the Pdf is a bitmap of the contents (e.g. the text is not editable)